# the newline is not presented in a JSP but on stdin it does

Tags: java, css, jsp

console output from string variable (it contains linebreaks):

> 1. value.
> 2. value.
> 3. value.
> 4. value.

in jsp page it looks like:

> 1. value. 2. value. 3. value. 4. value.

then I use `<pre>` tag to output linebreaks in jsp page. The whole output in jsp page is in the `div` with class:

> .center { margin: 0 auto; width: 60%; }

So that long lines is not affected by the above style and go out to the right corner of the screen... For instanese, the next line is not affected by `width: 60%` style:

> 5. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
>      it to make a type specimen book and It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

How preserve linebreaks in jsp and in the same time preserve the the appearence of the `.center` class?

jsp part:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="center">
<div id="rules">
    <c:forEach var="s" items="${values}" varStatus="loopCounter">
        <pre class="sansserif"><c:out value="${s.info}" /></pre>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your JSP

Comment: @home topic updated

Comment: you have to use <br> in the jsp, because html will interpret \n as whitespace.